# Can't find a way to disable line wrapping in MSysGit for commit messages vi/vim (by default around 74 chars)

Tags: git, vim, vi

I have tried a few times in the past (googling and trying things) to disable the small 74 character default line/word wrapping settings in MSysGit.  I tried looking through the vim directories under msysgit, my windows user directory for settings, nothing.  I can't find any documentation to disable this.

I'm using  1.7.11.msysgit.1

How do i turn off the line wrapping/word wrapping completely or at least increase the characters it wraps at to something really large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i figured it out.  For anybody else interested in this, edit the file: [git]\share\vim\vimrc

and in the line below, change the 74 to your desired width.  It's not perfect (it will still force a line wrap after the set characters if you ever reach them) but it's at least somewhat customizable.  Maybe removing it will work better.

autocmd Syntax gitcommit setlocal textwidth=74

Comment: Thanks for finding this! I replaced 'textwidth=74' with 'nowrap' and it got me what I wanted.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should avoid messing with Vim's system settings. This is especially the case if you are on a Linux/Unix system with no admin rights and this issue is also a problem for you (I got this same behaviour on Linux). You should modify your vimrc file instead.

To find out where is the vim's vimrc file, issue `:version` command in vim and scroll down until you see the `user vimrc file:`. This is it.

Modify it to change the textwidth only:

```
autocmd Syntax gitcommit setlocal textwidth=0
```

which should disable automatic text wrapping at 74th character. You can also remove all the auto commands with:

```
autocmd! Syntax gitcommit
```

To see what are the actual commands before removing them, issue the above command without exclamation mark.

Comment: Thank you that's what I was looking for.  However is there a sequence of paths where vim looks for such settings.  I would like to do what you suggested (it works) but put it into the git directory.  I'm using a portable version of MSysGit and dont' want to have to set this up on every machine i have Git on.  I just sync the git directories and i would like to be good to go.

Comment: @Coder in such case your own answer seems to be what you are looking for after all. If it works for you and the portable msysgit you are using than you should probably stick to it :) I thought I just add my 0.02$ for folks with different setup. Or correct me if I am missing something.